# How to copy all filed rows from one table to an other

Tags: excel, vba

HI I'm using this code to copy a fixed range from sheet "t1" to the first empty row in sheet "t2". I would like to select all rows that have value on the first column. Example. In the example i would like to copy all values starting at john an ending at 44 ( rows 2, 3, 4 and 5)

```
1 Name address zip
2 john   aaa    11
3 jane   bbb    22
4 carl   ccc    33
5 jeff          44
```

Here is the code I'm using.

```
Sub Botão1_Clique()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set copySheet = Worksheets("t1")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("t2")
copySheet.Range("A3:E3").Copy


pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True



End Sub
```

Comment: To get non blank range, resize to desired column, use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` and then resize back to cover other columns.

Comment: First empty row on t2 or the last row of t2?

Comment: last row on t2, T2 would store all values I enter during the day in T1, every day I change the values on t1 and at the end of the day I want to copy every thing to t2 in a big list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below using the `AutoFilter` method, to allow copying all rows in worksheet("t1") in case there are rows with data, but empty in column A.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Botão1_Clique()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range

Set copySheet = Worksheets("t1")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("t2")

copySheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter
copySheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>" ' <-- sut autofilter to exclude blanks on column A

Set Rng = Intersect(copySheet.UsedRange.Offset(1), copySheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) ' <-- set range to only visible rows without the header row

Rng.Copy
pasteSheet.Range("A" & pasteSheet.Cells(pasteSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues   ' <-- paste values to first empty row at "t2" worksheet

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked! I appreciated the comments helped to understand what was going on!

Comment: Just one question is it possible to not select the first row?

Comment: Yes, but I need to modify a few code lines, making it a little less cleaner, is it important for u ?

Comment: @Aman try edited code, it will copy the range without the first row

Comment: thanks it worked, it was not that important that is why I had already marked as answered, but it will speed up the process.